# Why do I get \n instead of a new line getting data from AJAX?

Tags: php, newline

I have a problem: so I have a data thats coming out of the database and stored in a text area. When the user changes the data in the text area, the content is sent to javascript and via AJAX (POST to a PHP script) the database is updated. This works fine until the user starts adding newlines. Then javascript transforms this into a \n-character and thus it gets stored in the database as \n.

What I want is to have actual newlines in my database and not the \n newline-characters. Is there any way that I can use php to replace the \n with an actual newline (NOT a br)? I have tried altering the database field after the edit with the char(10), but for some reason this is not working in the script except when I do it manually in phpmyadmin?

When editting with a full php request, the newline in a text area is correctly stored as a char(10) in mysql, not as \n.

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Which OS is used on the server? UNIX/Windows?

Comment: php does not output `\n` as new line. Try to `str_replace` it with `<br>`

Comment: Try replace "\r\n" with ""<br />

Comment: "What I want is to have actual newlines in my database and not the \n newline-characters" Wat?

Comment: change column type to TEXT

Comment: I suppose there is something converting the \n into \\n on the javascript side. Check out what data exactly are being sent in the HTTP request from the javascript to confirm. Then debug the javascript.

Comment: `\n` _is_ the sequence that denotes a newline. Show us the code you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store it as it is but escape first with [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

`real_escape_string` converts what is a newline into the 4 character string '\n\r'

```
$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($text);
```

Comment: @JeffreyMDeMeulemeester Yep, thanks, my first answer was a bit rushed and I deserved the -1, I replaced it later with this new answer.

Comment: the new one is even worse

Answer (score -2):

Use `[nl2br][1]` function to replace `/n` with newline

Insert line breaks where newlines (\n) occur in the string:

```
<?php
echo nl2br("One line.\nAnother line.");
?>
```

The browser output of the code above will be:

```
One line.
Another line.
```

Comment: This is not what I want... I want to store them correctly in the database using char(10).